# Error while building kernel 2.6.32-754.18.2 - SELF TEST FAILED /usr/lib64/hmaccalc

Tags: unix, compilation, linux-kernel, kernel

I am building the kernel rpm version 2.6.32-754.18.2 which has been failing with ‘SELF TEST FAILED’ message. I tried to explore further and found there are either some possibilities with the permissions or it is a prelink issue.

I am trying to build the kernel with a non root user.

:

```
+ sha512hmac /scratchpad/workdirs/NeoUser/build/RPM/BUILDROOT/kernel-2.6.32-754.18.2.el6test1 .x86_64/boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-754.18.2.el6test1.x86_64
+ sed -e s,/scratchpad/workdirs/NeoUser/build/RPM/BUILDROOT/kernel-2.6.32-754.18.2.el6test1.x 86_64
SELF TEST FAILED (/usr/lib64/hmaccalc/sha512hmac.hmac)
```

In order to find the fix I found here (end of the page) that mentions that /tmp should be mounted as 'exec' rather than 'noexec' and my fstab has 'tmp' entries like:

```
/dev/mapper/vgroot-plat_tmp /tmp ext4 defaults 1 2
tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs defaults 0 0
```

If I am not wrong tmpfs /dev/shm means it consumes space from RAM. What edit should I do here such that 'exec' as an option is used by tmp and I can use it to build my RPM.

I tried to edit tmp permissions and it is failing assuming my fstab is still correct.

Also I read a blog that suggested to use : ‘/usr/sbin/prelink -av –mR’  to fix the issue but the command generates huge output with following lines:

```
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/lib64/librpm.so.1.0.0 has a dependency cycle
Laying out 4 libraries in virtual address space 0000003000000000-0000004000000000
Random base 0x00000038e7600000
Assigned virtual address space slots for 64-bit x86-64 ELF libraries:
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2                                  0000003930a00000-0000003930c22190
/lib64/libaio.so.1                                           0000003930e00000-0000003931000a80
/lib64/libc.so.6                                             0000003931200000-0000003931593928
```

Comment: can you post rpm spec file ? the error is post kernel build.

Comment: Thanks but I could fix the error by remount tmp filesystem with exec permissions.